# Enqueue styles before scripts Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I get some issue when putting **.css** file into the `<head>`

The function which I use works great but files added after all the `<script>` tag and I would like to add them before.

```
function custom_styles() {
  echo"
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/custom.css' type='text/css' media='all'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/screen.css' type='text/css' media='all'>
  ";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_styles' 10 );
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why aren't you using `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: For sure it's better like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `wp_head` actions defined by user is triggered after the ones defined by wordpress, so your content will be added at the end of `<head>` tag. You can change the priority of action to value below default ( 10 ) , `add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_styles', 1 );`, or you can use more appropriate action [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and method [wp_enqueue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    // add js file in html header
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

see [more example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Examples)